# Why is the Eisenstein series holomophic?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

I am trying to learn modular forms. The first example that I encountered is the Eisenstein series 
$E_{2k}(z) = \sum_{(m,n)\in \mathbb{Z}^2\setminus (0,0)} \dfrac{1}{\left(m+nz\right)^{2k}}$.

I can understand that it satisfies the $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ condition. But I am unable to understand why it is holomorphic in the upper-half plane. What is it's limit at $i\infty$?  It would be really helpful if you could explain using some basic theorem of complex analysis like the convergence of a sequence of holomprhic functions.

Comment: Also, although the transformation under $z\To {az+b\over cz+d}$ is algebraically obvious, it does depend on pointwise absolute convergence for a simple argument for correctness.

Answer (score 5):

On compact subsets of the upper half-plane it is uniformly convergent,
at least if $2k\ge4$. Now use the fact that a limit of a uniformly
convergent sequence of holomorphic functions is holomorphic.

As $z\to i\infty$, $E_{2k}\to\sum_{m\in\Bbb Z,m\ne0}1/{m^{2k}}=2\zeta(2k)$.

Comment: And this also shows why $E_2$ cannot be done as easily as $E_4, E_6, \dots$.

Answer (score 2):

For $k \ge 2$, it converges uniformly on $\Im(z) > t$ so that the limit of the series is the series of the limit which is $2 \zeta(2k)$.

Also (since it is $1$ periodic and analytic on $\Im(z) > 0$) 
$f_{2k}(q) = E_{2k}(\frac{\log q}{2i\pi})$ is analytic on $0 < |q| < 1$, and 
$q =0$ is a removable singularity since $\lim_{q \to 0} f_{2k}(q) = 2 \zeta(2k)$.

Thus for $|q| < 1, \Im(z) > 0$ : $$f_{2k}(q) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n q^n, \qquad E_{2k}(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n e^{2i \pi n z}$$
which together with $E_{2k}(\frac{az+b}{cz+d})= (cz+d)^{2k} E_{2k}(z)$ when $ad-bc=1$ is the definition of a modular form of weight $2k$.