# How do I see that Eisenstein Series is uniformly convergent on every compact subset?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

I need to show that Eisenstein series $\sum\limits_{c,d\in \mathbb{Z},(c,d)\neq 0}\frac 1{(cz+d)^k}$ is holomorphic, ([Why is the Eisenstein series holomophic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2340821/why-is-the-eisenstein-series-holomophic)), and it suffices to show that it is uniformly convergent on every compact subset of upper half plane.

I can see that the series is absolutely convergent by using big O. I may try to find $M_n$ so that $\mid f_n(x)\mid \leq M_n$ and $\sum M_n$ converges. Is it the right idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|cz+d|^2 = \|(c,d)M_z\|^2, \qquad M_z = \pmatrix{\Re(z)&\Im(z)\\1&0}$$

Find the SVD $$M_z = V_z S_z W_z$$
then $$\inf_{\|(c,d)\|=r} |cz+d| =\inf_{\|(c,d)V_z\|=r} \|(c,d) V_z S_zW_z\| = S_z(1) $$ where $S_z(1)$ is the smallest singular value, which is continuous in $z$ and non-zero for $\Im(z)>0$.

From there, for $k>2,\Im(z)>0$ $$|\sum_{c^2+d^2>r^2} (cz+d)^{-k}|\le \sum_{c^2+d^2>r^2} |cz+d|^{-k}\le \sum_{c^2+d^2>r^2} S_z(1)^{-k}(c^2+d^2)^{-k/2} $$ ie. the LHS $\to 0$ as $r\to \infty$ locally uniformly on the upper half plane.

Comment: Thanks! What's the idea of the proof? To be quite honest, I'm quite lost what is done here! Could you briefly explain what is done?